# xfce4-terminal open new tab instead of new instance

Tags: firefox, terminal, command-line-interface, xfce

I want Firefox to open a new tab in the existing terminal window, instead of opening a new instance, when firefox requires CLI application. Could not find "new tab instead of a new instance" feature in Xfce terminal. Is there any plugin or a script for it? I don't mind if it opens a new instance when I click the terminal button, I need requests coming from Firefox to be opened in the existing terminal. Is there any workaround?